# Which Electronic Scrabble Games / Platforms Offer The Hardest Computer Opponents?

Tags: scrabble

One can do a google search to find which websites and which smart devices have Scrabble applications, but I find that computer players vary widely and are often misclassified.  For example, Lexulous is an example of a site where the computer players are grossly overrated. I remember when I played Scrabble on my iPod (remember those?  I am old) there was also an overrating and the quality of the computer players were relatively poor.  Sometimes, a computer has trouble using 1 or both blanks at the same time, playing tactical Scrabble to open up the board when I try to close the board, and time management (only using a fraction of what they are given).

So where can I find a truly difficult computer opponent?

Comment: Upvoted because this is a genuine concern for the discerning Scrabble player - finding an AI that's not an idiot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two well-known Scrabble AIs.   One is the commercial [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maven_%28Scrabble%29) which is made by Atari and bundles with most official Scrabble versions.  The alternative is called [Quackle](http://people.csail.mit.edu/jasonkb/quackle/) and is free open-source and of comparable strength.